# Testing Camel REST component endpoint producer template

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I'm trying to rest my route with a new [Camel Rest component](http://camel.apache.org/rest.html) available from version 2.14 :

```
@Produce(uri = "rest:test.get/company/{name}")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;
```

And `ProducerTemplate` which corresponds to this kind of rest endpoint is basically not yet implemented in that version.
What would be the best way to test that kind of endpoints?

Answer (score 3):

Current Camel Rest component only work for the Consumer (Server) side. By suggestion is you can use [camel-restlet](https://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) or [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html) to send the plain HTTP request for testing.

```
@Produce(uri = "restlet:http://localhost:808/test.get/company/{name}")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;

testProducer.requestBodyAndHeader(null, "name", 123, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [camel-restlet](https://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) or [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html)

```
**application.properties**

@Produce(uri = "{{url.router}}")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;
```

or

```
@Produce(uri = "http://localhost:8080/test/router")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;
@Test
public void testHttpMock() throws InterruptedException {
    testProducer.requestBodyAndHeader(null, userApi, passwordApi);
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```